# Dplyr: filter last entry for date in a series

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to filter only the last date entry in a time series for every occurrence where there was more than one for a given month.

As an example in a table like this:

```
obs <- c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B")
date <- c("2017-01-01", "2017-01-01", "2017-02-01", "2017-02-01", "2017-03-01", "2017-03-01", "2017-03-02","2017-03-02")
num <- c(1000, 1800, 2000, 2900, 3000, 3400, 3500, 3400)
dat <- data.frame(obs, date, num)

    obs       date  num
1   A 2017-01-01 1000
2   B 2017-01-01 1800
3   A 2017-02-01 2000
4   B 2017-02-01 2900
5   A 2017-03-01 3000
6   B 2017-03-01 3400
7   A 2017-03-02 3500
8   B 2017-03-02 3400
```

A simple selection for "A" would be:

```
x <- dat %>%
  filter(obs=="A") %>%
  select(obs, date, num) %>%
  mutate(date = ymd(date))

  obs       date  num
1   A 2017-01-01 1000
2   A 2017-02-01 2000
3   A 2017-03-01 3000
4   A 2017-03-02 3500
```

So, there are now two entries for the third month and I would like to keep only the most recent entry for that month. I thought it would be a straightforward thing to do so I did:

```
x <- dat %>%
  filter(obs=="A") %>%
  select(obs, date, num) %>%
  mutate(date = ymd(date)) %>%
  arrange(date) %>%
  slice(which.max(date))
```

But I get just the last entry instead with the other ones removed. What am I missing? The output should be:

```
  obs       date  num
1   A 2017-01-01 1000
2   A 2017-02-01 2000
4   A 2017-03-02 3500
```

Comment: 1. Your expected output is the same as the one you get with simply filtering `obs == 'A'`. 2. You need `filter` there or`slice(-which.max())`, 3. There should be a `group_by` in there.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the output.

Comment: Running your code, I get only the last row of output  This is with dplyr 0.5.0 and lubridate 1.6.0.  What versions are you using?

Comment: Tim, I also only get the last row. Dplyr 0.5.0 and lubridate 1.6.0

Comment: Oh, I misread. :)  I thought you wanted one row and were getting 3, when in fact it was the opposite.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to group by `month(date)` and then filter for the last date:

```
dat %>% filter(obs=="A") %>%
        mutate(date = ymd(date)) %>%
        group_by(obs, m = month(date)) %>% 
        filter(date == max(date))
#     obs       date   num     m
#1      A 2017-01-01  1000     1
#2      A 2017-02-01  2000     2
#3      A 2017-03-02  3500     3
```

Comment: So to get the expected output, the last line would be filter(date == max(date))! Can you modify your answer and i will accept it? Thank you!

Comment: ...and drop the grouping column (just to get the output exactly as requested)

`dat %>% filter(obs=="A") %>%
  mutate(date = ymd(date)) %>%
  group_by(obs, m = month(date)) %>%
  filter(date == min(date)) %>%
  .[-4]`

Answer (score 2):

We can do this using `base R`

```
i1 <- with(dat, ave(as.integer(as.Date(date)), obs,
     format(as.Date(date), "%m"), FUN = function(x) x== max(x)) & obs=="A")
dat[i1,]
#  obs       date  num
#1   A 2017-01-01 1000
#3   A 2017-02-01 2000
#7   A 2017-03-02 3500
```