# R: Replace value in a row with lead value dependent on a conditional

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data set containing the following variables: `ID`, `Date` and `Firm_name`. The problem is that although the ID value is unique and the same for a firm, they tend to change their name over time.

What I want to do is ensure that each firm (identified using their ID) only has one name. Preferably the name from the latest data value (by date), but that is not a must.

My experience with R is limited to performing simple tasks, not editing the data like this so I'm at a loss. From my experience using Stata I thought I could use lead/lag and write a for-loop with if-conditionals, however I couldn't get this to work.

This is what I have:

| ID | Name | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Alpha | 4/12 |
| 01 | Alpha | 5/12 |
| 01 | Beta | 6/12 |
| 01 | Beta | 7/12 |
| 02 | Cola | 6/14 |
| 02 | Cola | 7/14 |
| 03 | Pepsi | 3/10 |
| 03 | Pepsi | 4/10 |

This is what I want:

| ID | Name | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Beta | 4/12 |
| 01 | Beta | 5/12 |
| 01 | Beta | 6/12 |
| 01 | Beta | 7/12 |
| 02 | Cola | 6/14 |
| 02 | Cola | 7/14 |
| 03 | Pepsi | 3/10 |
| 03 | Pepsi | 4/10 |

As you can see, one firm (identified by ID) is now described using the same name for all rows. As stated above, I would prefer if the name which is used is the one with the latest date, but this is not strictly necessary.

Comment: Add your data in a reproducible form with desired results you want.

Comment: See  the edit. My code is not really going to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How's this? It adds a column to the existing data frame with the `Firm_name` from the latest date:

```
library(dplyr)

(dt <- data.frame(
  ID = rep(1:5, 2), 
  Date = seq(from = as.Date("2016-01-01"), to = as.Date("2016-01-10"), by = 1), 
  Firm_name = letters[1:10]))
```

#### Raw data

```
  ID       Date Firm_name
1   1 2016-01-01         a
2   2 2016-01-02         b
3   3 2016-01-03         c
4   4 2016-01-04         d
5   5 2016-01-05         e
6   1 2016-01-06         f
7   2 2016-01-07         g
8   3 2016-01-08         h
9   4 2016-01-09         i
10  5 2016-01-10         j
```

_

```
dt  <- group_by(dt, ID)
key <- filter(dt, Date == max(Date))
key <- select(key, -Date)
left_join(dt, key, by = "ID")
```

#### Joined data

```
      ID Date       Firm_name.x Firm_name.y
   <int> <date>     <fctr>      <fctr>     
 1     1 2016-01-01 a           f          
 2     2 2016-01-02 b           g          
 3     3 2016-01-03 c           h          
 4     4 2016-01-04 d           i          
 5     5 2016-01-05 e           j          
 6     1 2016-01-06 f           f          
 7     2 2016-01-07 g           g          
 8     3 2016-01-08 h           h          
 9     4 2016-01-09 i           i          
10     5 2016-01-10 j           j
```

Answer based on: [Dplyr: filter last entry for date in a series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43145578/dplyr-filter-last-entry-for-date-in-a-series)

Comment: Could you add some comments for educational purposes?

Answer (score 1):

With your sample data

```
dd <- read_table("ID   Name    Date
01   Alpha   4/12
01   Alpha   5/12
01   Beta    6/12
01   Beta    7/12
02   Cola    6/14
02   Cola    7/14
03   Pepsi   3/10
03   Pepsi   4/10")
```

If you assume it's already sorted by date, then you can just use replace all names with the last name

```
library(dplyr)
dd %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(Name=last(Name))

#      ID  Name  Date
#   <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1    01  Beta  4/12
# 2    01  Beta  5/12
# 3    01  Beta  6/12
# 4    01  Beta  7/12
# 5    02  Cola  6/14
# 6    02  Cola  7/14
# 7    03 Pepsi  3/10
# 8    03 Pepsi  4/10
```

If you needed to sort by date, you could add in an `arrange()` but you don't have proper date values here in the example.

Comment: Thank you, that worked as the data was sorted by date. Also, I didn't know that group_by() was a thing in R. That would have made it all much simpler as it follows the same logic as Stata. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(dplyr)

#convert Date column to 'Date' type column
df$Date <- as.Date(paste0(df$Date,"/2017"),format = "%m/%d/%Y")

df %>%
  arrange(ID, desc(Date)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
#This will filter the latest Name for an "ID"
  filter(row_number()==1) %>%
  select(ID, Name) %>%
#below join will update the Name in original data
  right_join(df,"ID") %>%
  select(ID,Date,Name.x) %>%
  `colnames<-`(c("ID","Date","Name")) %>%
  mutate(Date=format(Date,"%m/%d"))
```

Output is:

```
     ID  Date  Name
  <int> <chr> <chr>
1     1 04/12  Beta
2     1 05/12  Beta
3     1 06/12  Beta
4     1 07/12  Beta
5     2 06/14  Cola
6     2 07/14  Cola
7     3 03/10 Pepsi
8     3 04/10 Pepsi
```

```
#sample data
> dput(df)
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), Name = c("Alpha", 
"Alpha", "Beta", "Beta", "Cola", "Cola", "Pepsi", "Pepsi"), Date = c("4/12", 
"5/12", "6/12", "7/12", "6/14", "7/14", "3/10", "4/10")), .Names = c("ID", 
"Name", "Date"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```